# GitLab CI/CD - Pipeline gets stuck when using Runner on my own Host

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci-runner

I've setup CI/CD on GitLab for my toy project. After installing the Runner **on my own host** and activating it for my project, I double-checked everything by

1. running `gitlab-runner verify` and got the result

[image]

2. On GitLab, I got the result after finishing the registration step (`gitlab-runner register`)

[image]

The content in `config` file for GiLab Runner is as following

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "localhost"
  url = "https://gitlab.com/"
  token = MyTokenProvidedByGitLab
  executor = "ssh"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "root"
    host = "MyHost.org"
    port = "22"
    identity_file = "/d/ssh/id_rsa"
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
```

However, the pipeline gets stuck

[image]

Furthermore, I also executed the command `gitlab-runner run` to try making the pipeline run, but it seems to not work, below is the picture

[image]

Is there anything wrong in my setup steps?

Comment: was the pipeline created before runner registration? are you trying to run a ci job without tag?

Comment: Hello @piarston, yes it was. Where is the tag located?

Comment: I would start by cancelling the pipeline and running it again. If it doesn't work, check that your runner accepts to run [untagged jobs](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/runners/#runner-is-allowed-to-run-untagged-jobs)

Comment: add your gitlab.yml file please

Comment: I am facing the exact same issue. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 2):

**you need to start your gitlab runner service process**

first test that the runner is properly installed 
inside your repository dir

run

```
gitlab-runner exec shell <Job-Name>
```

if that's running properly your project then

my guess is that if we press the stages buttun 
 we see that there isn't any available runner for this job

open command line and run **( inside your project dir containing the .gitlab.yml
)**

```
gitlab-runner.exe run
```

then if its start the job add this command as a service on your host on startup

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion! When I execute `gitlab-runner run` I got something about `[session_server].listen_address not defined, session endpoints disabled  builds=0` and it just stands there forever. The pipeline still gets stuck as the picture I showed above.

Comment: add git-lab runner to path and run  inside the repo dir